# assertArrayEquals testing

Tags: java, junit

I have this problem in testing `assertArrayEquals` in JUnit as I am not sure how it works. I created a method so I can understand it but its not working. Can anyone help sort this out here is the code:

```
public class ArrayAssert
{

    public boolean check(int[] arr2)
    {

        final int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        arr2 = new int[arr1.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        {

            if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
            {
                System.out.println("false");
                return false;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("true");
        return true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayAssert obj = new ArrayAssert();
        int[] arr2 = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter numbers to check");
            arr2[i] = scan.nextInt();
            obj.check(arr2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test case I made using JUnit

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ArrayAssertTest {

int []val = new int[]{1,2,3};

    @Test
public void testCheck(int[] val) {
    boolean expect = true;
    boolean result ;

     assertArrayEquals(expect,result);
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

"expect" and "result" in your test code should be the filled arrays itself.

See the [JUnit Assert API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) for the method parameters for more details.

Comment: why do i have to do that?? I am filling the array using val[] array. Thus I am checking the array is equal the other array

Comment: I added the link to the assertMethod from the JUnit API to the answer. The answer of the comment is, that this is the way it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a little bit
Here is the class that I want to test:

```
public class ArrayAssert {

public int[] create(){
    int [] array = {1,2,3};
    return array;
}
}
```

and here is my other class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ArrayAssertTest {
int []val = new int[]{1,2,3};

@Test
    public void testCheck() {

     ArrayAssert sample = new ArrayAssert();
     assertArrayEquals(val, sample.create());
}
}
```

there were 2 problems in your code that I noticed:
first: any test cant take any parameters
second: assertArrayEquals only takes arrays as parameters, your parameters were booleans, it would have been just fine, if they were boolean array.

I hope the code and explanation makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/), which has lots of built in assertion checks for arrays, collections, etc.